# using radio buttons in php jqGrid

Tags: javascript, php, html, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid using php. In one of the columns i want to use two radio buttons (Yes/No). I have used a custom formatter for this..

```
$(function () {
  function myelem (value, options) {
    var radio1 = document.createElement('input');
    radio1.id = 'radY';
    radio1.type = 'radio';
    radio1.name = 'appr';
    radio1.value = 'Yes';

    var radio2 = document.createElement('input');
    radio2.id = 'radN';
    radio2.type = 'radio';
    radio2.name = 'appr';
    radio2.value = 'No';

    var label1 = document.createElement('label');
    label1.setAttribute('for', radio1.id);
    label1.innerHTML = 'Yes';

    var label2 = document.createElement('label');
    label2.setAttribute('for', radio2.id);
    label2.innerHTML = 'No';

    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(radio1);
    container.appendChild(label1);
    container.appendChild(radio2);
    container.appendChild(label2);

    return container;
  }

  function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if(operation === 'get') {
      return $(elem).val();
    } 
    else if(operation === 'set') {
      $('input',elem).val(value);
    }
  }

  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "fetch.php?sqlselect=1",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["Role", "Region", "Approved"],
    colModel: [
      { name: "role", width: 60,editable:true},
      { name: "region", width: 60,editable:true},
      { name: "approved", width:250, editable:true, edittype:"custom", editoptions: {custom_element: myelem, custom_value:myvalue}}
     ],
   onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastSel){
      jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastSel);
      lastSel=id;
      }
        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,
      {
    keys : true,
    url : "edit.php"
      } );
    },

    .............
```

Everything works fine when edited except the radio button column. I can see the radio buttons onClick. But once i press enter the radio button value is not passed to my edit page. That's understandable coz myval function is reading the div element and not a radio element. Since there are two radio buttons (with the same name, so at point only one can be checked Yes/No), and it's not a single entity like a text box, in order to 'return' a myelem i had to use a div. Is there a way I can do this where i can fetch the radio element value?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.. All I needed to do was this:

```
 function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if(document.getElementById('radY').checked) {
        return "Yes";
    }
    else {
        return "No"; 
    }
 }
```